# REST Call with values containing apostrophe

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint-2013

I using REST and ajax to fetch data from SharePoint using the ablve:

```
https:xxxxxxxx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/RMSD_Tasks?$orderby=IssueValue asc,StatusValue desc&$filter="+dropValue+" eq '"+secondFilterVal+"'&groupby=IssueValue/StatusValue
```

Everything works just fine, except one case. Sometimes the value of secondFilterVal is "Manager's Bulletins" with an apostyrophe. When I make the call I get a bad request message. What can I do here? Unfortunately, the text "Manager's Bulletins" can't be changed. I was thinking about using "$filter=substringof.....", but it works so well with everything else. Thansk!

Comment: Have you tried escaping the singe quote as %27 or \'?

Comment: try using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the values before putting them in url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Lauri and @charlietfl for the comments. The information @charlietfl gave me was specially useful, because it opened my eyes to different options, and encodeURIComponent() was the way to go. Reading MDN's [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and this great link to [REST Filters](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/06/special-characters-in-rest-query-filter.html) helped me solve my issue using the above code:

For some strange reason you need the apostrophe twice: The result `Manager%27%27s%20Bulletins` works perfectly.

```
var str = fixedEncodeURIComponent("Manager's Bulletins");

function fixedEncodeURIComponent(src) {
    return encodeURIComponent(src).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct. It's true that the apostrophes need to be doubled in order to escape them, but I don't think `!`, `(`, `)`, or `*` should be doubled. Doubling them seems to cause the query to fail.